# What is the best workspace color profile to use while designing for billboard Ads in both Illustrator and Photoshop?

Tags: print-design, color-profile

What is the best workspace color profile to use while designing for billboard Ads in both Illustrator and Photoshop?

Comment: Hi Qussai, thanks for your question and welcome to GDSE. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve and why you are asking this question? Did you search the web and why aren't the answers you found not adequate? Thanks and enjoy our site!

Comment: Hi, I would like to thank you first thing. actually I have been involved in Graphic design and digital printing for long time, but still having difference in color matching and files exchange between different PCs. I always search the net for such issues, but it is not quite enough.

Answer (score 1):

The one that the provider gives you.

In case the provider does not give you one, try using a generic one like Fogra 39.

I mention this because digital print can hold a saturated Total Ink Coverage (TOC) and this profile uses a 330%

But probably it is a good idea to send a small sample using a couple of different profiles and see which one you like most.